# Are there LaTeX performance profiling tools?

Tags: compiling, tools, performance

The most obvious way to speed up LaTeX processing is to split a large and complex document into smaller pieces.  For example, Makefiles, `\beginpgfgraphicnamed`/`\endpgfgraphicnamed` when using TiKZ, and splitting a large file into separate chapters are all helpful in splitting a large job into smaller, hopefully independent pieces.  But sometimes this is not enough -- many packages do complicated things under the hood, leading to slow document processing.

> Are there any tools to help isolate
>   the culprits?

It would be great to also have the profiling tool provide suggestions on ways to speed things up.

Comment: You kids today are so spoiled. My first PC, a 386 with 1M of RAM was underpowered to run LaTeX and a run on my class handouts would typically take 30 minutes or more to typeset a dozen pages. We never profiled anything cause it was ALL slow.

Comment: See also [profiling - Package loading speeds - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141661/package-loading-speeds) & maybe [macros - How to implement (low-level) arrays in TeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex) for some discussion how to write fast TeX code as a TeX programmer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps not quite what you're after, but the trace package is used by the LaTeX Project to get a feel for the 'cost' of different things. This package lets you include every TeX expansion and assignment in the log file. So you can check how many lines a particular function adds to the log, which gives you an idea of how hard TeX is working to do whatever you've asked for. Other than that, the approach I take is to create simple test files (say one with a loop to repeat one function many times), then use 'time' at the command line to see what changes as I alter the input.

Comment: Note. There's the (relatively) new `l3benchmark` library, although I'm not sure how to use it

Answer (score 21):

pdfTeX (which is the default nowadays, even if you're generating DVI) has functions for doing timing tests. Use `\pdfresettime` to start it off and do ‘something’ with `\pdfelapsedtime` when you're done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfresettimer
\usepackage{expl3,tikz}
\showthe\pdfelapsedtime
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The value of `\pdfelapsedtime` is the number of seconds elapsed multiplied by 65536.

Answer (score 10):

tikz/pgf seems to provide a general profiler built on top of `\pdfelapsedtime` to optimise TeX code. See "44 Profiler Library" in its manual from a recent CVS checkout. The stable release pgf 2.0 is out of date.

Comment: For anyone still wondering in '21, this should probably be the accepted answer, as pgf/TikZ provide a `profiler` library which does exactly what OP asked. Profiling of individual commands and environments has to be declared manually but the output is provided in the log _and_ in a special output file. This allows you to profile _à la_ MATLAB.

Comment: https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf (currently `67 Profiler Library`)